# how to install missing python modules offline without managers

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a device running an embedded OS (Custom Linux buildroot). It is offline and has **no** package manager (`apt`, `yum`, et al.) and Python has several missing modules, one of which is key for our application to run. Python also does not have `pip` either (which makes a kind of sense, it being an offline system).

**I cannot** rebuild the OS since it is currently running and mission-critical systems have to stay up.  All I need to do is add the Python `sqlite3` module to this thing and *poof*, application is in business.

On my development box, I have tried doing a

```shell
pip freeze > reqs.txt
```

to see what modules I am using, but none of the Python default modules are listed, most notably `sqlite3`.

Can I just copy the module directly from my Python modules folder to the device's Python modules folder and be done, or is this going to make a mess?

Forgive the seemingly noob question, but I've never played with this kind of offline scenario when Python isn't fully realized on the machine., and given that I can't have the app throwing errors on the running box, I'm leery of just tinkering.

Comment: sqlite is unlikely to become a tag here since it's a library for software developers to use and not a dbms to be installed. I recognise it has a comandline interface, but stackoverflow gets those questions and rarely U&L.

Comment: sqlite3 isn't a package you can install with pip anyway since it's bundled with python itself. I would rebuild the OS **on a virtual machine** and try to figure out why these files are missing. If they are not missing in the new OS build, then copy them out of the VM as they have a better chance of being compatible with what you have on your embedded machine, that what you have on your workstation.

Comment: @PhilipCouling yup.  that's what i wound up doing.  and as to WHY this happened: the previous dev/admin was a dumbass who obviously didn't know what he was doing.  can't even begin to understand why you'd edit python *intended for SCADA control* such that i has neither `sqlite3` or `socket`.  \**slap*\*  at any rate, thanks for the effort.  it was gratifying to know my solution wasn't terrible.  :)